# Tornado POST request not detecting json input as argument

Tags: json, post, tornado

I have written a service which takes a json as input. I am using the website [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it) to send post requests to check. Below is my code snippet:

```
class BatchSemanticSimilarityHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
 def post(self):
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token')
    data = json.loads(self.request.body)
    apikey = data["apikey"]
    try:
        UA = self.request.headers["User-Agent"]
    except:
        UA = "NA"
    if bool(usercoll.find_one({"apikey":apikey})) == True:
        sentence = data["sentence"]
        sentence_array = data["sentence_array"]
        n = data["num_of_results"]          
        if sentence is None or sentence_array is [] or apikey is None or n is None:
            self.set_status(200)
            output = {"error":[{"code":334,"message":"Bad Input data"}]}
            misscoll.insert({"apitype":"batchsemanticsimilarity","timestamp":datetime.datetime.now(), "ip":self.request.remote_ip, "useragent":UA, "uri":self.request.uri,"apikey":apikey, "output":output, "input":{"s1":sentence,"s2":sentence_array}})
            self.write(output)
            return
        results = nb.get_similar(sentence, sentence_array, apikey, n)
        print "results is",results
        output = {"similar_sentences": results, 'credits':'ParallelDots'}
        hitscoll.insert({"apitype":"batchsemanticsimilarity","timestamp":datetime.datetime.now(), "ip":self.request.remote_ip, "useragent":UA, "uri":self.request.uri,"apikey":apikey, "output":output, "input":{"s1":sentence,"s2":sentence_array}})
        self.write(output)
        return
    else:
        rejectcoll.insert({"apitype":"batchsemanticsimilarity","apikey":apikey,"timestamp":datetime.datetime.now(), "ip":self.request.remote_ip, "useragent":UA, "url":self.request.uri})
        self.write({"error":[{"code":333,"message": "Bad Authentication data"}]})
        return
```

The json that I am giving as the body of the request is as below:

```
{
"sentence": "BJP leads in Bengaluru civic body`s poll, all eyes on JD(S)",
"sentence_array": [
    "Narendra Modi is the prime minister",
    "Sonia Gandhi runs Congress",
    "Sachin is a good batsman"
],
"apikey": "DyMe1gSNhvMV1I1b20a7KARYIwuQX5GAQ",
"num_of_results": 2
}
```

I have verified on jsonlint that this is a valid JSON.
However while sending the request it gives me below error:

```
  ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Can anyone please help me sort this out!!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object that you are passing in POST request is encoded into the url.
JSON library cannot read the encoded data.So you need to decode the url first.
Decoding of url can be done using **urlparse** library in python.so you need something like this.
        `post_data=urlparse.parse_qsl(self.request.body)`

According to your need of final format to read there are various methods in urlparse.check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

or

As specified in the docs you can override a method to enable JSON parsing

`def prepare(self):
    if self.request.headers["Content-Type"].startswith("application/json"):
        self.json_args = json.loads(self.request.body)
    else:
        self.json_args = None`

check [this](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html)

Comment: The issue has been solved!! The solution above mentioned is not exactly the issue here. The json was being parsed correctly as I had checked the same code from my local. The issue was due to closed ports on the server which I was trying to hit through nginx

Comment: @jyoti If u have added this before,it would have been easy for detecting that it's the server issue.I went for the parsing issue seeing the error.Anyways if its server closed port issue,why there is parsing error?